# "Which" or "That" in the sentence and the equivalent sentence with "which"

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-choice, relative-clauses

I made the following sentence:

> For example `div[@id=”content” or contains(@class,”content”)]` can be
>   used to identify **a node that** the value of *its* id attribute is “content” or
>   the value of *its* class attribute contains “content”.

I would like to know "a node that" is correct or I should say "a node which", if I want to use "which", how can I avoid using "its" (italic) in the sentence above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is neither.

The problem is (that) you tried to use *that* as a relative pronoun, but you have nothing to relate the two clauses.

---

Let's take a closer look at your sentence.

> For example `div[@id=”content” or contains(@class,”content”)]` can be used to show a node **that** the value of *its* id attribute is “content” or the value of *its* class attribute contains “content”.

This could look like *that* relates to *its*, but actually it does not.

Let's try something simpler:

> Two sentences: This is a cat. This cat sleeps a lot.
>   One complex sentence: This is the cat that sleeps a lot.
>   ​　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　(= This is <del>a</del> **the** cat <del>this cat</del> **that** sleeps a lot.)

That's how a relative pronoun works in general. It has to replace something in the subordinated clause, usually either the subject or the object of the subordinated clause.

---

So, how should we fix your sentence?

My first thought was to use *that* as a subordinating conjunction instead (*to show [that ...]*), but according to the intended meaning, *to obtain* fits the sentence better. (For the sake of simplicity, I'll assume that we will obtain only one node.) So, let's consider the whole idea (with the verb *to obtain*) as two sentences first:

> 1. For example, `div[@id=”content” or contains(@class,”content”)]` can be used to obtain a node.
> 2. The value of the attribute `id` of **this node** is “content” or the value of the attribute `class` (of this node) contains “content”.

Fix #1: Use ***of which***

An obvious way to join the two sentences is to use *which* in the place of *node* in the subordinate clause (sentence 2). The result will look like this:

> For example, `div[@id=”content” or contains(@class,”content”)]` can be used to obtain the node **of which** the value of the attribute `id` is “content” or the value of the attribute `class` contains “content”.

Fix #2: Use ***whose***

Though *of which* is possible, it's more common to simply use *whose*. *Whose* is corresponding to *its* in the subordinated clause, which is the OP's original problem. Using *whose* instead of *of which*, we get this:

> For example, `div[@id=”content” or contains(@class,”content”)]` can be used to obtain the node **whose** the value of attribute `id` is “content” or the value of attribute `class` contains “content”.

But, wait! We can even make it a little better:

> For example, `div[@id=”content” or contains(@class,”content”)]` can be used to obtain the node whose **either** the value of attribute `id` is **or** the value of attribute `class` contains “content”.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I think the sentence you suggested is not what I mean. I want to say "For example `div[@id=”content” or contains(@class,”content”)]` can be used to identify or distinguish a node that the value of its id attribute is “content” or the value of its class attribute contains “content” ".  Suppose there are many nodes, and this expression is used to identify a specific node

Comment: Excuse me, in my question I modified "show" to "identify" and I think it can be a relative clause

Comment: @Ahmad It depends on the meaning you want to say. If you replaced *show* with *identify* in the last fix in my answer, it would work, but I think it's still not what you want. Seeing your comment, I think you probably want this: *For example, `div[@id=”content” or contains(@class,”content”)]` can be used to obtain the node(s) whose either the value of the attribute `id` is (“content”) or the value of the attribute `class` contains “content”.* (The first "content" can be omitted.) Does that sound right for you?

Comment: Yes that sounds right, you suggest to use "whose" and removing "its", no matter where it is? because my problem was how to omit "its" while there is a distance between "that" and "its"

Comment: Yes. The main point is that you have to have something to relate the two clauses, i.e. the relative pronoun must stand for (or replace) something in the subordinated clause. In your case, it's *its*. I will edit my answer to accommodate your intended meaning.